# Inner product space - Linear algebra 2 - Positive attribute

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Lets say I have:
$<(a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2)>$ = $2a_1a_2 + 4b_1b_2$
I am going to check positive in order to refute Inner product space
I get $2a_1a_2+4a_1a_2$ = $6a_1a_2$
Now, can I say that if $a_1<0$ and $a_2>0$ so I get that refute? I am stuck an hour trying to think about it.
Thanks.

Comment: You are talking about axiom four, I think: $(\forall v\in V):\langle v,v\rangle\geqslant0$ and $\langle v,v\rangle=0\iff v=0$.

Comment: and you have $V = R \times R$

Comment: Yea, exactly, that axiom. Is it true what I am saying?

Comment: But on the first one, if its bigger or equal to zero.

Comment: You have observed that, say,  $\langle (-1,1) , (-1,1) \rangle = 6(-1)(1) < 0.$

Comment: I think you are correct. This does not make an inner product space, since axiom 4 fails. The axioms are listed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/inner-products/info

Comment: @311411 Exactly, so wait, I have to give a example of my refute? a numbered one? with real numbers and such? or I can just say what I did?

Comment: And thanks for the help :)

Comment: No, your way is fine. Obviously $6 a_1 a_2 <0$. Also, you can use the commands langle and rangle: ```\langle (1,2),(3,4) \rangle```.  It looks nicer in LaTex and MathJax

Comment: @311411 sorry for the misunderstanding, but what is langle and raNGLE? is it related to linear? or its something about latex and such? I saw something like that TEX exchage, thats why.

Comment: Oh I see what you say, now i understand, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V$ be the usual real vector space of ordered pairs of real numbers. Your reasoning shows that the mapping $(\alpha,\beta)=((a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2)) \mapsto 2a_1a_2 + 4b_1b_2$ cannot be an inner product for this space. It cannot be, since the positivity axiom (axiom number four) fails.

All the axioms are listed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/inner-products/info

But the relevant one here is:

4. $\quad (\forall v\in V):\langle v,v\rangle\geqslant0$ and $\langle v,v\rangle=0\iff v=0$.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack, cheers